# Convertir código Java a Kotlin

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin, byte

Buenas estoy intentando convertir un código de Java a Kotlin pero me dio problemas al convertirlo.
No programo en Java o en Kotlin ya que estoy programando en Flutter pero necesitaba agregar una función en Nativo.

Java

```
public static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] array){
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++){
        buffer.append(Character.forDigit((array[i] >> 4) & 0xF, 16));
        buffer.append(Character.forDigit((array[i] & 0xF), 16));
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Kotlin

```
fun byteArrayToHexString(array:ByteArray):String {
        val buffer = StringBuffer()
        for (i in array.indices)
        {
            buffer.append(Character.forDigit((array[i] shr 4) and 0xF, 16))
            buffer.append(Character.forDigit((array[i] and 0xF), 16))
        }
        return buffer.toString()
}
```

Pero da el siguiente error:

Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public inline infix fun BigInteger.shr(n: Int): BigInteger defined in kotlin

En la línea:

```
buffer.append(Character.forDigit((array[i] shr 4) and 0xF, 16))
```

Y el error:

Type mismatch: inferred type is Byte but Int was expected

En la línea:

```
buffer.append(Character.forDigit((array[i] and 0xF), 16))
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en la conversión de los operadores a nivel de bits. Por ejemplo `>>` en kotlin es la función `shr()` y esa función se encuentra en los enteros así que para usarla se convierte `array[i]` en entero con la función `toInt()`

```
fun byteArrayToHexString(array: ByteArray): String {
            val buffer = StringBuffer()
            for (i in array.indices) {
                buffer.append(Character.forDigit( array[i].toInt().shr(4)  and 0xF, 16))
                buffer.append(Character.forDigit(array[i].toInt() and 0xF, 16))
            }
            return buffer.toString()
        }
```